# Static electricity underneath the print with mystery adhesion and warping

Tags: adhesion, warping, creality-cr-6

Any idea what could be causing a static discharge on large prints? It seems that it's mostly visible when it's done and the print is being removed, it keeps zapping (can barely feel it. Small prints don't seem to be doing this. This leads me to believe it's one of the moving parts rubbing and creating it? I'm using CR6-SE with a glass bed and a full metal hotend and print in PLA PRO (which is another way of saying PLA+ I guess, but the reel said PLA PRO) (in case this was relevant). Another question, I have mystery first layer adhesion issues, could static be responsible for it? After washing the bed with water, it seems to be sticking again for a single print. And I have mystery warps as well. At first I thought it was normal warping, however, it seems to warp in the centre as well. Here's an image of a print:

[image]

It looks like someone punched the holes in specific areas. On the other side, they correspond to joints where thin walls ended. I've been suffering from a lot of warp, but it was always corners, never like this. Could this also be caused by static?

Lastly, is there any risk for the printer itself? The shock seems to be limited to bed/print only.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! I've embedded the image for you, linking to off-site content is usually not very future proof, instead we use the SE dedicated image storage that is retained as long as this site exists.

Comment: Are you sure it is static electricity? Have you checked in the dark when removing the print? Furthermore, you are dealing with a large under-extrusion, you need to address that first (your bottom layer lines do not touch each other so you can see through). It is not the initial bed to nozzle distance, the other layer have the same problem.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for fixing the post.
I'm quite sure it's static electricity. When I move the print next to my skin, I can feel the pull on the hairs (that electric feeling like an electrified balloon or plastic film that just keeps sticking back onto the hand). I haven't tested in the dark, no. It seems to be very weak. It also seems to be only on the underside of the print as I grab it from the top and then the bottom makes the noise. 
I fixed the extrusion issue. Turns out the spring wasn't tight enough and it was making it uneven, however remaining issues remain.

Comment: It may be worth adding, I always had issues with the print sticking, but I went with a bad solution of overheating the bed to 90 degrees for the PLA Plus to stick. It would become soft at that point (ripping it off the bed would deform it: tested on the side line that is printed at the beginning) and the grip wasn't as strong as just washing the bed with soap. It mostly would warp, but I think that's sensible because warp affects the soft layers, which in that case was the overheated one.